# How can I change the speed of the keyboard slide in/out animation?

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

I am very confuse with my small test app.When i do on the Textfield the keyboard comes slowly I want to increase the keyboard time.Can anybody tell me that how  i can increase the time of KeyBoard up and down?

Comment: you want to increase the time or the speed??? they are inversely proportional you know. so if you increase the time it will be slower... anyways.. i don't think you can change it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed of the system keyboard can be retrieved via the `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey` and is read-only.

UPDATE: How to get the values. In the notification listener:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification 
{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;

    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
}
```

Comment: What would you use the animation curve for?? Or how would you use it?

Comment: The animation curve is zero.  I thought it would be some sort of ease in ease out type of timing curve, but it is not.  The curve is set to zero.